# An algorithm to produce data for an animated line graph

Tags: python, algorithm, animation, graph

I'm processing data that describes progress of a process with many parts. Each part has a number of milestones. The parts are not equal, but the ratios are given.
I would like to produce an animated line graph as the final result. 
For each part of the process there are several milestones. I need to calculate the current completion, as a percentage for each part at each of many different times. The different times correspond to the 'frames' of the animation.

Example data with three milestones:

```
Task1, 22  , 24.5 , 27.6  
Task1, 30% , 35%  , 35% 

Frames 0-21  :  y = 0  
Frame  22:  y = 30%  
Frame  23:  y = 30% + 35% *(23-22/24.5-22)  
Frame  24:  y = 30% + 35% *(24-22/24.5-22)  
Frame  25:  y = 30% + 35% + (25-24.4/27.6-24-5)  
Frame  26:  y = 30% + 35% + (26-24.4/27.6-24-5)  
Frame  27:  y = 30% + 35% + (27-24.4/27.6-24-5)  
Frame  28+  y = 30% + 35% + 35%
```

This is assuming that no work has happened on the subtask until the first milestone is reached.

I'd like to create a function in python that accepts the task and ratios as a list, and a maximum frame number and returns a list of values for each frame.
This is what I have tried so far which is incorrect.

```
from math import floor, ceil
from itertools import chain

data = [[1,2.5,4.5,7],[4,6,9,11],[0,0,9,11],[1,1,1,9]]
ratios = [[25,20,20,35],[30,30,30,10],[0,0,50,50],[10,10,15,65]]

frame_count = int(ceil(max(chain.from_iterable(data))+1))
print "frame count is ", frame_count
frame_times = range(0,frame_count)
print "frame_times are " , frame_times

frames = []

for r, part in enumerate(data):
ratio = ratios[r]
y_list = []
print "part is ", part
print "ratios are ", ratio

for i in range(len(part)-1):
    Tlast = part[i]
    Tnext = part[i+1]
    Rlast = ratio[i]

    for frame in frame_times:
        print "frame : %r, Tlast: %r , Tnext: %r" %(frame, Tlast,Tnext)
        if frame == 0 or (frame < Tlast and max(y_list) == 0):
            y_list.append(0)
            print "%r appended" %(y_list[-1])
            continue
        elif frame == Tlast :
            y_list.append(y_list[-1] + ratio[i])
            print "%r appended" %(y_list[-1])
            continue
        elif Tlast < frame and frame < Tnext:
            y_list.append(y_list[-1] + ratio[i] * ((frame-Tlast)/(Tnext-Tlast)))
            print "%r appended" %(y_list[-1])
            continue
        else :
            print "Problem occured no value found for frame."
            print "y_list is ", y_list
            exit()
    frames.append(y_list)

print "Data points are"
print data

print "ratios are ", ratio
print ratio

print "y_list is ", y_list
```

Many thanks for any suggestions on how to correct this and improve the method.

I wonder whether it would be better to have the frames as the middle loop and the data points as an inner loop. I don't know how to code that where the two loops are not independent of each other. Something like this:

```
loop through the frames:  
    while frame < Tlast :
       y_list.append(calculate y)  
       increment frame

    increment Tlast
    increment Tnext

    while Tlast < frame < Tnext : 
         y_list.append(calculate y)
         increment frame
    increment Tlast
    increment Tnext

    while frame > Tnext :
        y_list.append(calculate y)
        increment Tnext
        check whether to increment frame and continue
```

Comment: incorrect how? do you get an error? traceback? or just not providing the expected result?

Comment: It's not providing the required result.

Comment: please post what's expected and what you get

Comment: Is the indentation correct? I don't think so: `for i in range(len(part)-1):` and the rest should be within the first loop or no wonder why it's not working.

Comment: you could edit your post to explain that: it would be better for the question and the formatting. I'll certainly look into it.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I'll edit the code in the question to correct the indentation.